# How to release resources from processes killed by grunt-contrib-watch?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm trying to use the module `grunt-contrib-watch` to restart my node.js server whenever certain files change. I already use grunt to run the server, jshint, and the template compiler, and I know those functions work. Here's the task to start the server:

```
grunt.registerTask('runServer', 'Starts the server.', function(){
     grunt.log.writeln('Starting server...');
     var done = this.async();
     var child = grunt.util.spawn({
         cmd: process.argv[0],
         args: ['server.js'],
     }, function(){
         grunt.log.writeln('Server stopped!');
         done(true);
     });
     child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
     child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
 });
```

Here's the config for the watch task:

```
watch: {
    all: {
        files: ['some/files/*.js'],
        tasks: ['default'],
        options: {
            spawn: true,
            interrupt: true,
            reload: true,
        }
    }
}
```

When the task is restarted, the server fails because of an "EADDRINUSE" exception, which I take to mean is because the previous child process didn't release the port it was using, which is strange - I do see the "Server stopped!" message. I have tried this with all combinations of the three options, and I looked on the github page for grunt-contrib-watch, and nothing showed anything. How can I make the interrupted node.js process close all its resources before the next one tries to start?

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to perform a child process spawn? In every case that I have spun up a server, I have simply done something like this:

grunt.registerTask('runServer', 'Starts the server.', require('./server'));

The watch task remains the same as you have it listed. Grunt automatically kills the previous run of that task as long as it is not a child process. This seems to work just fine for me.

However, if you NEED to spawn a child process and then kill it:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        server = undefined;
...
grunt.registerTask('runServer', 'Starts the server.', function(){
    grunt.log.writeln('Starting server...');

    if (server)
        server.kill('SIGUSR2');

    server = spawn('node', ['server.js'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
}
...
grunt.registerTask('default', ['runServer']);
```

Comment: This didn't work; the server quits immediately. I don't know why calling `require` doesn't work but the call to `server.listen` returns immediately.

Comment: I believe you will have to configure your server.js a little differently for this to work (e.g. module.exports will have to return a function that will work as a grunt task). Could you post the gist of what your `server.js` looks like?

Comment: I could, but unfortunately in production grunt is not used at all and the server has to be able to be started with `node server.js`. I might just go back to C-c every time I change a file :(

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer to show how to trigger `node server.js`. Let me know if that does / does not work.

Comment: One other comment, sorry for spamming you here, you can probable set `spawn` to false on your watch task if you are also spawning a separate process already in your JS code.